# When to use "me and my __" and "my __ and me"?

Tags: differences, sentence, formality

When is it correct to use, for example "me and my wife" and "my wife and me", which is correct and what's the difference?

Comment: Either one may be used (there is no difference) whenever one could use _me_ by itself, and not where one couldn't. E.g, _Bill met me/me and my wife/my wife and me at NorWesCon last year_. But **not** _*Me/Me and my wife/My wife and me met Bill at NorWesCon last year_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess that's why we should write, "One day, my dog and I went for a walk." :-P

Comment: @John: Coming from you, that seems like an extraordinarily prescriptive position. I'm more comfortable with [this "descriptivist" position](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:1111344388#q=isbn%3A1111344388++%E2%80%9CJohn+and+me+went%22&tbm=bks) *The prescriptive rule we are taught that may keep us from saying “**John and me went to the store**” is in fact **not logical at all** and cannot be generalized to pronouns other than **I**!*

Comment: @Pitarou: I was being a bit tongue-in-cheek saying *name the important one first* in the context of ***self*** and ***spouse***. But if you listen to the two different pairs of in-laws identifying the happy couple to others, I bet you'll soon discover that in most cases each pair name ***their own child first***.

Answer (score 2):

In the real world, either one is acceptable.

If you're dealing with an *insufferable pedant* however, or aspire to become one, you'll want to insist upon "**My Wife and I**". No substitutions permitted.

Comment: Not always.  *My wife and I went to the store,* but *Fred met with my wife and me.*

Comment: @user61979 Insufferable pedants treat grammar as folklore. Nobody ever said their corrections are always... well, correct. :P